# Cannot call consturctor of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter when using @Order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a library that contains the class `QuerySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` for implementing Web-Security. A stripped-down version of this security config class is as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(101)
public class QuerySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    public QuerySecurityConfig(){
        ...
        this(Arrays.asList("/v2/api-docs");
    }
    
    public QuerySecurityConfig(List<String> ignoredRestEndPoints){
        ...
        this.ignoredRestEndPoints = ignoredRestEndPoints;
    }

    public QuerySecurityConfig(List<String> ignoredRestEndPoints) {
        this();
        this.ignoredRestEndPoints.addAll(ignoredRestEndPoints);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web){
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(this.ignoredRestEndpoints.toArray(new String[0]));
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to instantiate a Bean of this security class using one of the constructors as follows

```java
@Bean
@Order(200)
public QuerySecurityConfig getQuerySecurityConfig() {
    List<String> excludedEndpoints = new ArrayList<>();
    excludedEndpoints.add("/seller/**");
    return new QuerySecurityConfig(excludedEndpoints);
}
```

However, I keep running into the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 101 was already used on com.example.app.security.QuerySecurityConfig$$
EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ca9e6a6c@4981b83, so it cannot be used on com.example.app.security.QuerySecurityConfig@2e549515 too.
```

How can I invoke the constructor on such a class when `@Order` is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I am attempting to create two Beans of the `QuerySecurityConfig` class. The first bean is being created due to the `@Configuration` annotation over `QuerySecurityConfig` and the second one is being created manually by the `getQuerySecurityConfig()` method, annotated by `@Bean`. This is causing a duplication of the `Order` and hence the exception.

I managed to fix this by simply excluding `QuerySecurityConfig` from the Component-Scan. After this, I also had to add `@EnableWebSecurity` to my configuration class since it was being ignored along with the rest of the `QuerySecurityConfig` class.